# Relation between $\|\mathcal F_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$ and $\|f\|_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

By  $L^2({-\infty},{+\infty})$ we denote the Hilbert space  of real functions that are square integrable in Lebesgue's sense:
$$L^2(\mathbb R)=\left\{f: \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx<+\infty\right\}$$
with respect to the inner product and $L^2$-norm that are
$$\langle f, g \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx\qquad \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R)}}$$
Given $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ we denote by $\hat{f}$ the Fourier transform of $f$,
$$
\hat{f}(\omega)=\mathcal F_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}\left(f\right)(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} f(x) e^{-i\omega x}dx.
$$
The Plancherel theorem states that the integral of a function's squared modulus is equal to the integral of the squared modulus of its frequency spectrum. My question is the following; given $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and $\mathcal F f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, is it possible to relate $\|\mathcal F_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$ with $\|f\|_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}$? Is $\|\mathcal F_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\|f\|_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}$?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can think about extending $f$ to $\tilde{f}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $\tilde{f}$ to be $0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\pi,\pi]$. Then $\mathcal{F}\tilde{f}=\mathcal{F}_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be supported on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then by Plancherel's theorem
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^2\,dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f(x)|^2\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\hat f(\omega)|^2\,d\omega,
$$
buit in general there is no relation to $\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\hat f(\omega)|^2\,d\omega$ (other that strict inequality if $f$ is not identically $0$.) Consider for instance $f_\delta(x)=\dfrac{1}{\delta}\,f\Bigl(\dfrac{x}{\delta}\Bigr)$ with $0<\delta<1$. Then $f$ is supporded on $[-\delta\pi,\delta\pi]\subset[-\pi,\pi]$ and $\widehat{f_\delta}(\omega)=\hat f(\delta\,\omega)$. The $L^2$ norm of $f_\delta$ goes to $\infty$ as $\delta\to0$, while the $L^2$ norm of $\widehat{f_\delta}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ remains bounded.